# Сообщение ответ клиенту с помощью winsock2?

Tags: c++, winsock

Как отправить сообщение клиенту средствами winsock2?
Пример отправляю сообщение на сервер, и нужно что-бы сервер ответил, принял ли message? Как реализовать приём сообщение от сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите статью, описан пример работы с WinSocks2 (клиент\сервер).
http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/

Comment: Для отпраки сообщений используется send, для приема соответственно recv. На сервере тоже можно отправлять сообщения, а на клиенте прочитать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот например, как то так:

```
do {  
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
```

Это все в коде сервера.